# Error when trying to delete some customers

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have bought a theme and there are some customers created by the theme creators.

When I try (from the backoffice) to delete one of the customers I made everything works but if I try to delete a pre-existing customer I get this:

```
TypeError: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/Mcrypt.php:171
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/Mcrypt.php(171): rtrim()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(452): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\Mcrypt->decrypt()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer.php(476): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(1008): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer->_afterLoad()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(543): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->load()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/CustomerRegistry.php(81): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->load()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php(385): Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry->retrieve()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository->getById()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->___callParent()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Plugin/CustomerPlugin.php(204): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->getById()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Plugin\CustomerPlugin->aroundDeleteById()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Interceptor.php(59): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassDelete.php(56): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->deleteById()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/AbstractMassAction.php(65): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete->massAction()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\AbstractMassAction->execute()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callParent()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassDelete/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->execute()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callParent()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(145): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassDelete/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete\Interceptor->dispatch()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#38 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#39 {main}
```

The strangest thing is this: I copied the root folder of Magento and the DB on another server and from there I can easily delete those customer I could not delete from the first server...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be in the Old server you missing the mcrypt PHP Extension.

To Install the Extension: **apt install php7.4-mcrypt**